# How to detect multiple barcodes/QR codes in a TIFF image and return their value + position?

Tags: barcode, qr-code, tiff

I'm currently trying to achieve this:

I have a very large TIFF image, which contains scanned documents. The image contains invoices with barcodes/QR codes, followed by multiple other scanned documents related to the invoice which preceded them. This can be repeated multiple times ( the TIFF image may look like [invoice] + [documents] + [invoice] + [documents] ... )

I need a program (doesn't really matter in which language but I'd prefer either Java, JavaScript, PHP, C++ or Python) that takes said TIFF image, scans all the barcodes and returns their values and their position in the image (either which page it is on or it's absolute position, but the page is preferable, I know for certain that there won't be multiple barcodes on one page). The goal is to split this TIFF image into multiple PDF files, each containing only one invoice and all of the documents that belong to the invoice.

I have the latter part done already. I intend to use *ImageMagick* to split the TIFF file into multiple files (tested, works). I have also tried multiple barcode scanning methods, but met critical problems at every one. And that's the point of my question:

Is any of my presumptions false? Is there a better way/library/SW that you know about that could work?

Libraries/SW I tried so far:

**ZXing port for PHP**: Can't work with TIFF files

[ZXing github](https://github.com/khanamiryan/php-qrcode-detector-decoder)

**Quagga for JavaScript**: Can't work with TIFF files either.

[Quagga github](https://github.com/serratus/quaggaJS)

**ZBar code reader**: The best looking one by far. I managed to scan multiple QR codes in one TIFF image using CMD (Windows), but didn't find a way to get their positions. Also found out that C++ and Python versions exist, but didn't get to try them out just yet.

Thanks for any ideas/corrections.

Answer (score 0):

The best one I heard -that is subjective ofc- is [Barcode Rendering Framework](http://barcoderender.codeplex.com/)

I'm not sure if it can detect multiple barcodes on a page but it can detect many different types of barcodes.

And it's also Open Source..